# Export Silverlight Datagrid to Excel using COM object

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight, excel, silverlight-4.0

I have a datagrid on a silverlight 4 application that I am trying to export to excel by calling the COM component for Excel in silverlight. It keeps error-ing out and tells me that the functionality is not supported. I can't quite figure out what is wrong and believe my code is solid, obviously not though.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim excel As Object = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        excel.visible = True

        Dim workbook As Object = excel.workbooks

        workbook.add()

    Dim sheet As Object = excel.activesheet
    Dim cell As Object = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    'populate the excel sheet
    For Each item In ActivityTypeCountDataGrid.ItemsSource

        cell = sheet.cells(i, 1)
        cell.Value = item.Activity_Type
        cell.ColumnWidth = 50

        cell = sheet.cells(i, 2)
        cell.Value = item.Activity_Type_Count
        cell.ColumnWidth = 50

        i += 1
    Next item



End Sub
```

Here is the data grid
[image: DataGrid]

Here is the error
[image: Error]

Comment: Is this an Out Of Browser application?

Comment: no, it runs within the browser

Comment: You will need elevated trust for this to work.

Comment: I believe you have to be OOB to use COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1) Convert this application to a Silverlight OOB applicaiton.

2) Pass the data to a WCF Service.  Have the service create the Excel Workbook.  Pass the file (as a `byte[]`, `IEnumerable<byte>`, etc) back to the Silverlight app and prompt the user to save the file using a `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: The datagrid is pulling its data from a view within the database which already loads into the WCF service. So from what you have advised I could write a method in the WCF service that could create the Excel Workbook based off of the method already pulling the data and then pass it to the user on the front end of the app?

Comment: Yes, if you WCF service already has access to the data, there is no need to pass it from Silverlight to the service.

Comment: no luck writing this in the WCF service as I am not able to import     Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation in the WCF service

Comment: Excel will need to installed on the server hosting the WCF service